# Background image not showing up in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Other browers like chrome shows up fine. IE9 just shows the gradients no images.

Code CSS

```
body {
background: 
 url('../images/adventure/background.png') 
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 40%, rgba(149,147,160,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(40%,rgba(255,255,255,0.4)), color-stop(100%,rgba(149,147,160,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 40%,rgba(149,147,160,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png'), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 40%,rgba(149,147,160,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 40%,rgba(149,147,160,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png'), linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 40%,rgba(149,147,160,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#9593a0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Comment: I see no "IE9" in the comments? Only IE 6-8 and 10

Answer (score 5):

You need a closing semicolon (`;`) on the first `background` like this:

```
background: url('../images/adventure/background.png');
```

Comment: So I fixed the problem in IE9 it was the ; thank you.


Now IE9 makes the bottom color fade over the image other browsers the image fades behind the gradient.

Comment: other browsers image fades over gradient ---- delete last comment.