# Background not showing up in IE9 unless gradient is disabled

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, css

I have the following code:

```
body{
  font-family : Arial, helvetica, verdana;
  background: url('../images/waves.png');
  background-position: 50% 0%;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80848c', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

and the result in IE9 is that the gradient is rendered and the image doesn't show.
I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964561/background-image-not-showing-up-in-ie9) and followed it to the last letter. This person was able to solve his problem but I am lost as to what I am missing. What I do know that if I disable the gradient is that it'll show up (in Dev mode)
The document uses a html5 doctype (if this helps).

Comment: The fully opaque gradient is being drawn over the background image. What is the desired result?

Comment: i noticed that you must have 8 digids in startColorstr like : startColorstr="#80848c88". it works perfectly that way

Comment: The filter/gradient isn't actually counted as a background.  I'm fairly certain that it is something that exists on a different *layer*.  I don't think there's anything you can do about it other than not use it.

Comment: @Savi Thanks. That's the exact answer.I ran into this: http://bricss.net/post/12423845540/working-with-8-digit-hex-colors-argb-in-internet which explains why the extra 2 hex digits. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put 2 extra digids at startColorStr like this:

```
startColorstr="#80848c88"
```

it will work perfectrly.